# How to save Video in SQL Server and display in listview and play it in video player on asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq, c#-4.0

I am developing a asp.net project and want to do do task done asps here is a problem

i want to save a video in SQL Server table and also play that video in web player
how can i save a video in MS SQL Server using C#. and display list of video in asp:listview
to play the video. after clicking on video which is in view in list view.

Thank you

Comment: use varbinary datatype in SQL Server to store video

Answer (score 1):

Since it is too much code for me to proccess and put here I'd suggest to look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21480/Video-Uploader-Control-for-SQL-Server) solution where everything but the listview part of your problem is explained.

Comment: That code is Not working did you ever worked with this code before?